# add column value of oracle database table via php query

Tags: php, oracle

Hi, I have a table in oracle database. It has columns `purchase` `sale` `income`.

Now I want to show `sum` of those values in `INCOME` column and show in php page that total income is `sum[INCOME]`. I tried to use a query with function. query seems not working. Here is the code.

```
<?php
function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) {
    if ($fractional) {
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
    }
    while (true) {
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
        if ($replaced != $number) {
            $number = $replaced;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}
$c = oci_connect('SYSTEM', 'passward', 'db');

$result1 = oci_parse($c,"SELECT sum(INCOME) FROM TABLE WHERE SALE_DATE='$rdt'");    
oci_execute($result1);
$row = oci_fetch_array($result1, OCI_ASSOC);    
while($row = oci_fetch_array($result1, OCI_ASSOC))
{
    $total=$row['sum(INCOME)'];
    echo formatMoney($total, true);
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's incorrect, give the aggregate function an alias using the keyword `as`:

```
$result1 = oci_parse($c,"SELECT sum(INCOME) as total_income FROM TABLE WHERE SALE_DATE='$rdt'");
```

And then you can fetch it like:

```
$total=$row['total_income'];
```

Or you can let the query remain the same and instead fetch it with:

```
$total=$row[0]; //aggregate functions return only single row, so this
                //basically means fetch the first row
```